# Scala covariant type T occurs in invariant position

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have this trait:

```
trait Delivery[T] {
  def form(): Form[T]
}
```

where [Form](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form) is from play2 framework.

Then I have object that implements Delivery trait:

```
case class NewPostValidator(town: String, number: Int)

object NewPost extends Delivery[NewPostValidator]{
  def form(): Form[NewPostValidator] = Form(mapping(
    "town" -> nonEmptyText,
    "number" -> number)(NewPostValidator.apply)(NewPostValidator.unapply))
}
```

Now I want to write function which accepts List of objects that implements trait Delivery. And I can't write type for parameter of it. If I try to write this like

```
list: List[Delivery[AnyRef]]
```

I've got type mismatch error and if I change Delivery trait to:

```
trait Delivery[+T] {
    def form(): Form[T]
}
```

I've got Scala covariant type T occurs in invariant position error.
How can I describe type for this parameter?

Comment: What is the exact error? As comment above suggests, you can use List[Delivery[_]]. You should not be simply throwing in covariance if you're not sure what it means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [covariant type T occurs in invariant position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721936/covariant-type-t-occurs-in-invariant-position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want all the forms inside the method to be of the same underlying type or if you care about the return type inside `Form`. It would be good to understand what's going on here.

```
trait Delivery[T] {
  def form(): Form[T]
}

case class NewPostValidator(town: String, number: Int)

object NewPost extends Delivery[NewPostValidator]{
  def form(): Form[NewPostValidator] = Form(mapping(
    "town" -> nonEmptyText,
    "number" -> number)(NewPostValidator.apply)(NewPostValidator.unapply))

  def accept[T <: Delivery[_]](list: List[T]): List[Form[_]] = {
    list.map(_.form())
  }

}
```

Comment: Great. This is what I was looking for.